# Django URL with catch all except /admin and /blog

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to make a catch all URL in my Django project...

It works fine, but now i can't go to my /admin and /blog page .. any idea how I can do this?..

My urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^blog/$', 'apps.blog.views.index'),

(r'^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*)', 'apps.review.views.show_search'),
```

Comment: When I go to /admin  - it just make a search  ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle this manually with a RedirectView. You likely need to add the CommonMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings if it is not already in there.
(inserting 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware' into that list or tuple). It usually goes near the top of that declaration. Its documentation is here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware

You also need to be sure APPEND_SLASH is set to True in your settings.

Furthermore, your last pattern is likely to match anything, which I suspect could be the real culprit of your problem. A URL without a trailing slash has to fail to match any patterns in order for it to automatically redirect to one with a trailing slash per that middleware. I think you can fix the last URL pattern by appending /$ to that pattern

Answer (score 0):

The admin and blog urls have trailing slashes i.e. `/admin/` and `/blog/`. The urls with the trailing slashes should work at the moment.

If you want to make the urls work without the slash, you could add entries for `/admin` and `/blog`, and use [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView) to redirect.